# How to tell whether a checkbox is checked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

As most people know there are at least two (easy) ways to findout if a checkbox is checked.

`($('#checkbox:checked').val() != undefined)` OR `($('#checkbox').val() == 'on')`

Which of these two methods is best? why?

Comment: The value of a checkbox is not necessarily "on": if there is a "value" attribute, that will be what you get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that

```
$('#checkbox').is(':checked');
```

is the way to go.

Comment: re: why - because it automatically evaluates to a boolean true/false

Comment: Thanks mVChr - I forgot to add the explanation.

Comment: Just to add, there's also `if($("#checkbox:checked").length)`.

Comment: Just use the `checked` property of the checkbox element that has worked in every browser released since 1996. `$('#checkbox')[0].checked` will do it and will be more compatible and more efficient than using `is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're accessing the raw element, you should be able to use something like:

```
this.checked
```

But I don't know if there might be any cross-browser compatibility issues with this method.

Comment: This is good in the context of an event handler, and shorter than using the `is` filter, e.g. `$("#foo").change(function() { if(this.checked) {...} }); ` - and no, this is perfectly cross-browser.

Comment: You can reach the raw element by treating the jQuery object as an array, thus: using a numerical index. `$('#checkbox')[0].checked` *will* work.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
if ($('#myCheckbox').attr("checked")) { .. }
```

Anyways...I don't think any one of these is necessarily better or worse. jQuery is designed to work across browsers so any one of them should work.  Not sure anybody has taken the time to actually benchmark them for performance or anything...just do what you feel is most readable to you.

Comment: this no longer works in jquery 1.9+; you need to use $('#myCheckbox').prop('checked')