# Javascript on tick or on untick events for a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

Is it possible to fire an event when a checkbox is ticked, and a different one when it's unticked?

At the moment I'm using

```
$("#booking_checkboxes").on("change", "input", function(){});
```

but I'd like to know if the checkbox just changed to be ticked, or just changed to be unticked. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Just using `:checked` inside your handler isn't an option?

Comment: you mean this : .is (':checked') cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell whether a checkbox is checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915394/how-to-tell-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the same event is fired in both cases.  You'd have to check for the value of the input in the event callback:

```
$("#booking_checkboxes").on("change", "input", function(){
  if (this.checked) {

  } else {

  }
});
```

Comment: This is so obvious that I can't believe I didn't think of doing it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#booking_checkboxes").on("change", "input", function(){
   if (this.checked){
     // do what you want for when the element is checked

     // if you need to, you can trigger a custom event here..
     $('someelement').trigger('check_event');
   } else {
     // do what you want for when the element is NOT checked

     // if you need to, you can trigger a custom event here..
     $('someelement').trigger('uncheck_event');
   }
});
```